# Why does my FindGameObjectByTag() find the same object twice even though it's destroyed?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, saving-data

I'm trying to make a level saving script for an infinite level generator and its going alright so far. My level generation works in "tiles" which build together to make a maze like structure. My code finds the GameObject with the tag and uses it to get float/int values for its position/rotation and type. After that it destroys the Tile that was used and moves on to the next one. My problem is that even though my GameObject is destroyed at the end of one iteration my code ignores the second Tile and keeps saving values from the first one. Here's my code:

```
public void SaveLevel()
    {
        //Loop in charge of TileList
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            if(saveNum = true)
            {
                TileList[0] = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Tile");
            } else
            {
                TileList[0] = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Block");
            }


            
        
            if (TileList[0].gameObject.name.Contains("Hall") ) 
            {
                intTileList_forFile[i] = 0;
            }

            else if (TileList[0].gameObject.name.Contains("Corner") )
            {
                intTileList_forFile[i] = 1;
            }

            else if (TileList[0].gameObject.name.Contains("Edge"))
            {
                intTileList_forFile[i] = 2;
            }

            else if (TileList[0].gameObject.name.Contains("End"))
            {
                intTileList_forFile[i] = 3;
            }

            else if (TileList[0].gameObject.name.Contains("Middle"))
            {
                intTileList_forFile[i] = 4;
            }

            intTilePlacement_forFile[j] = TileList[0].gameObject.transform.position.x;
            intTilePlacement_forFile[j + 1] = TileList[0].gameObject.transform.position.y;
            intTilePlacement_forFile[j + 2] = TileList[0].gameObject.transform.position.z;

            intTileRotation_forFile[k] = TileList[0].gameObject.transform.rotation.x;
            intTileRotation_forFile[k+1] = TileList[0].gameObject.transform.rotation.y;
            intTileRotation_forFile[k + 2] = TileList[0].gameObject.transform.rotation.z;
            intTileRotation_forFile[k + 3] = TileList[0].gameObject.transform.rotation.w;

            Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion();
            rotation[0] = intTileRotation_forFile[k];
            rotation[1] = intTileRotation_forFile[k+1];
            rotation[2] = intTileRotation_forFile[k+2];
            rotation[3] = intTileRotation_forFile[k+3];


            Vector3 position = new Vector3();
            position[0] = intTilePlacement_forFile[j];
            position[1] = intTilePlacement_forFile[j+1];
            position[2] = intTilePlacement_forFile[j+2];

            tempB = TileList[0];

            Destroy(TileList[0]);

            

            j += 2;
            k += 3;

            tempA = null;
            tempB = null;
            TileList[0] = null;
        }

        saveNum = !saveNum;

        //tempA = Instantiate(tempB, position, rotation);
        //
        //if (saveNum = true)
        //{
        //    tempA.gameObject.tag = "Block";
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    tempA.gameObject.tag = "Tile";
        //}

        Debug.Log("Complete");
    }
```

PS: I understand using if-elses for something like this isn't good but I'm working on using Cases instead so bear with me :).

Answer (score 0):

"is destroyed at the end of one iteration my code ignores the second Tile"

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
```

Could this be the reason?

Comment: ah no , I made the loop go only twice because I have two Tiles that I'm trying to save. When I fix whatever's going on Ill make it go for however long it needs

Comment: //Loop in charge of TileList
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)

                TileList[0], not TileList[i]?

Comment: Since the TileList[i] is destroyed at the end I didn't see the need to make it a long array so its only one element long

Comment: It is necessary to decompose, it is difficult to understand what exactly is required from the code. And a lot of questions.  tempA - dont used.  if(saveNum = true) - will be executed only once depending on the current value of the variable. And null - only removes the link to the data. p.s. if(saveNum = true) must be (saveNum == true)

Comment: my bad, I wasnt exactly sure how to decompose this since I dont actually know where the error is occurring. Let me try to clear some things up:
After getting all the values (rotation/position etc.) I destroy the original Tile with the tag "Tile" and clone it with the tag "Block".
The reason for saveNum is used is so that after the tag is changed the boolean can see how many times it was changed and find out which tag to search for.
The 'rotation' and 'position' variables are used to instantiate the tile with the different tag.

If there are any more things I can help clear up let me know

Comment: After that - Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion(); You overwrite these values in a loop. Is that right? p.s. We need someone who is more familiar with the unity3d :)

Comment: yes the rotation and position values get overwritten each time since their values are also saved in the IntTileRotation/Placement arrays aswell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).